# Cakephp 3.x Exception render - different layout

Tags: cakephp, exception, layout, render, cakephp-3.0

This document shows how to assign layout for error:
`$this->layout = 'my_error';`

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#exception-renderer

But i've 2 different layouts for frontend and backend. When `NotFoundException` is thrown, i want to assign different layout accordingly.
How can i do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just check appropriate criteria and set layout accordingly in your template. For e.g.

```
if ($this->request->param('prefix') === 'admin') {
    $this->layout = 'admin';
} else {
    $this->layout = 'default';
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you so much.
I did check prefix param inside error400.ctp to identify backend or frontend and it's work like a boss.

Answer (score 0):

As @ADmad suggest.
Do check the request to identify frontend or backend inside error400.ctp file (you may have another error file, just is a example).
In my case use admin prefix, i did like this:

```
if (!empty($this->request->params['prefix']) && $this->request->params['prefix'] == 'admin') {
    $this->layout = 'Admin/default';
    $app = [
    'App.imageBaseUrl' => 'admin/img/',
    'App.cssBaseUrl' => 'admin/css/',
    'App.jsBaseUrl' => 'admin/js/'];
    Configure::write($app);
} else {
    $this->layout = 'Frontend/default';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to re-set layout you have to re-render the action, a redirect would be the most easy solution here. You could also use an AppView.

```
$view = new AppView();
$view->set($variables);
$view->render();
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#the-app-view